# jquery custom time format for datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, datetime-format

i am using [this](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) third party datetimepicker plugin for my date and time picking functionality. i want to customize my time format to 12 hour format with `AM/PM`, i have changed my code to achieve this

```
$('#startTime').datetimepicker({
            datepicker : false,
            format : 'g:i A'
});
```

this some how satisfied my requirement, when i select a time it displays in 12 hour format in the input box, but my date picker ui displays still in 24 hour format, i have tried this

```
{allowTimes:[
  '09:00 AM',
  '11:00 AM',
  '12:00 PM',
  '21:00 PM'
]}
```

but it doesnt work, is there a way so that i can change the default setting to 12 hours instead of 24 hours.

Comment: _change the default setting to 24 hours instead of 12 hours._ ? I thought you wanted the opposite o.o

Comment: @BatuZet yes..i corrected

Comment: You know about `hours12` property ? If you already know that and it does not suit you, then i guess you need to write a function for `onGenerate` or something. BTW if this is gonna be only about hours, you dont need a `datetimepicker` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the option `formatTime` as this formats the times in the datepicker UI:

```
$('#startTime').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: false,
    format: 'g:i A',
    formatTime: 'g:i A'
});
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn2jf/1/)

Comment: Now how do you use `allowTimes` option in this format for PM times? `allowTimes:['1:00 PM']` is displayed `13:00 PM`. Is there a way to display it `1:00 PM`?

Comment: I can't understand why that's not working - see a [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jn2jf/38/) for a Fiddle

Comment: Yeah, I can't get it to use AM PM in the alllowTimes list either.  Anyone know how to do this?